# AWS Server - holds 4 sites after DNS change 1 sites A record does not change

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I have an amazon AWS server running Ubuntu. It currently holds 4 websites, and I changed the DNS for these sites at 08:00 this morning.

It is now 15:30 in the afternoon, I set the TTL down to 60 however :

**3 of the 4 sites have propagated.**

**1 of the 4 sites is still responding to the old IP address still.**

Am I missing something?

Comment: When did you set your TTL to 60?

Comment: at 08:00 this morning ... it is now almost 15:00

Comment: And if you look at the old DNS record you're still receiving, what's the TTL on it?

Comment: How do I do that???

Comment: `ipconfig /displaydns` will show you the TTL of the record on your local machine in windows.

Comment: This is on a *nix server (ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

First, use `nslookup` to query your name servers (listed in the Route53 management console when you select your zone) directly.
You do it like this:

```
nslookup my.query.com ns-????.awsdns-??.???
```

If this query doesn't give you the right results, the issue is between the AWS console and Amazon's servers, so you should contact them.
If this looks OK (like I think it would), then you have a problem of propagation - some DNS server in your hierarchy (your PC asks server A, which asks server B, which asks... ending in Amazon's nameserver) is misbehaving, and not Amazon.

Comment: The strange thing is that The server holds 3-4 domains and all but 1 have resolved :/

Comment: @JustSteveKing, the name servers for the domains don't have to be the same - are you sure you're querying the right ones?